# Деление в столбик на Java

Tags: java, деление, длинная-арифметика

Нужно написать класс который бы делил одно число на другое, выводя деление в столбик. Деление целочисленное. Если остался остаток, просто вывести его в последней строке, если остается ноль его не выводим. Пример результата, который должен вернуться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
public class LongDivUtil {
    private String result = "";
    private int remDiv = 0;
    private int quotient;
    private int dividend;
    private int divider;
    private int[] numbersDividend;
    private String[] numbersOfDividendInStrVal;

    public LongDivUtil(int dividend, int divider) {
        this.dividend = dividend;
        this.divider = divider;
        this.numbersOfDividendInStrVal = (dividend + "").split("");
        this.numbersDividend = new int[numbersOfDividendInStrVal.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbersOfDividendInStrVal.length; i ++){
            numbersDividend[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbersOfDividendInStrVal[i]);
        }
    }

    public void executeDivision(){
        System.out.println("execute");
        System.out.println(this.dividend + "|" + this.divider);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        int tmpInt = numbersDividend[0];
        boolean  isContinue = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbersOfDividendInStrVal.length || isContinue; i++) {
            if (tmpInt >= divider) {
                quotient = tmpInt / divider;
                result += quotient;
                remDiv = tmpInt % divider;
                isContinue = false;
                System.out.println("result = " + result);////////////////
                System.out.println("remDiv = " + remDiv);//////////////
                if (remDiv != 0 && i != numbersOfDividendInStrVal.length - 1){//1
                    tmpInt = Integer.parseInt((remDiv + "") + (numbersDividend[i] + ""));
                    System.out.println(tmpInt);
                    continue;
                }
                if (i < numbersOfDividendInStrVal.length -1){//2
                    tmpInt = numbersDividend[++i];
                    isContinue = true;
                }
                continue;
            } else {
                if (tmpInt == 0){//4
                    result += tmpInt;
                    if (i < numbersOfDividendInStrVal.length){
                        tmpInt = i;
                    }
                    isContinue = false;
                    continue;
                }
                if (tmpInt < divider){
                    tmpInt = Integer.parseInt(numbersOfDividendInStrVal[i] + numbersOfDividendInStrVal[++i]);
                    isContinue = true;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        System.out.println("out");
    }
}
```

В нете, часто встречающийся вопрос, но ничего не находил в рекомендациях. Пока пишу сам, но получается, мягко говоря, не очень. Кто ни будь сталкивался с подобным?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Код стоит подправить, но представленный пример показывает основные принципы, которые необходимо реализовать.

```
public class LongDivUtil {
private int dividend;
private int divider;
private int n;
private StringBuffer dividendSB;
private StringBuffer result=new StringBuffer("");
private StringBuffer firstSplitedString;
private StringBuffer secondSplitedString;
private StringBuffer print=new StringBuffer("");


public LongDivUtil(int dividend, int divider) {
    this.dividend = dividend;
    this.divider = divider;
    result=new StringBuffer("");
    this.dividendSB=new StringBuffer(Integer.toString(this.dividend));
}
public void printSomeCharSomeTimes(String s,int n){
    for (int i = 0; i <n ; i++) {
        print.append(s);
    }
}
public StringBuffer returnResult(){
    print.append(dividendSB+"|"+divider+"\n");

    printSomeCharSomeTimes(" ",dividendSB.length());
    printSomeCharSomeTimes("-",Integer.toString(divider).length()+1);
    StringBuffer t=new StringBuffer("");
    for(int i=0;this.dividend>=this.divider;i++){
        print.append("\n"+t.toString()+this.getLeftDividendNumber());
        count();
        print.append("\n"+t.toString()+n*divider);
        t.append(" ");
    }

    if (this.dividend!=0)
        result.append(".");

    int numberOfDigits=5;

    while(this.dividend!=0&&numberOfDigits!=0){
        for (int i =0;dividend<divider;i++){
            dividend=Integer.parseInt(dividendSB.append("0").toString());
            if (i>0){
                result.append("0");
            }
        }
        count();
        numberOfDigits--;
    }
return result;
}

public int getLeftDividendNumber(){
    int i=1;
    while (Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(this.dividend).substring(0, i))<this.divider) {
        i++;
    }
    this.firstSplitedString = new StringBuffer(Integer.toString(this.dividend).substring(0, i));
    this.secondSplitedString = new StringBuffer(Integer.toString(this.dividend).substring(i, Integer.toString(this.dividend).length()));
    return Integer.parseInt(this.firstSplitedString.toString());
}

public void count(){
    this.n=this.getLeftDividendNumber()/divider;
    result.append(n);
    this.dividendSB=new StringBuffer(Integer.toString(this.getLeftDividendNumber() % divider));
    this.dividendSB.append(this.secondSplitedString);
    dividend= Integer.parseInt(this.dividendSB.toString());
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
LongDivUtil l = new LongDivUtil(234678,356);
    l.returnResult();
    System.out.println(l.print.toString());
}
}
```

В примере вывожу только результат целочисленного деления.

```
234678|356
      ----
2346
2136
 2107
 1780
  3278
  3204
```

Answer (score 8):

Смысл в том что в классе сначала реализуется конвейер деления. Каждый этап добавляется в строку результата. Потом сторка модифициреутся для отображения красивого деления в столбик.
На входе главного метода два числа(делимое и делитель), на выходе получаем строку - полную отрисовку деления в столбик. Метод легко тестируется.

```
public class Division {

    private StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    private StringBuilder quotient = new StringBuilder();
    private StringBuilder reminder= new StringBuilder();

    public String makeDivision(int dividend, int divisor) {

        if (divisor == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Divisor cannot be 0, division by zero");
        }

        dividend = Math.abs(dividend);
        divisor = Math.abs(divisor);

        if (dividend < divisor) {
            return "" + dividend + "/" + divisor + "=0";
        }

        String[] digits = String.valueOf(dividend).split("");
        Integer reminderNumber;
        Integer multiplyResult;
        Integer divisorDigit = calculateDigit(divisor);
        Integer mod;

        for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
            reminder.append(digits[i]);
            reminderNumber = Integer.parseInt(reminder.toString());

            if (reminderNumber >= divisor) {
                mod = reminderNumber % divisor;
                multiplyResult = reminderNumber / divisor * divisor;

                String lastReminder = String.format("%" + (i + 2) + "s", "_" + reminderNumber.toString());
                result.append(lastReminder).append("\n");

                String multiply = String.format("%" + (i + 2) + "d", multiplyResult);
                result.append(multiply).append("\n");

                Integer tab = lastReminder.length() - calculateDigit(multiplyResult);
                result.append(makeDivider(reminderNumber, tab)).append("\n");

                quotient.append(reminderNumber / divisor);

                reminder.replace(0, reminder.length(), mod.toString());
                reminderNumber = Integer.parseInt(reminder.toString());
            } else {
                if (i >= divisorDigit) {
                    quotient.append(0);
                }
            }

            if (i == digits.length - 1) {
                result.append(String.format("%" + (i + 2) + "s", reminderNumber.toString())).append("\n");
            }
        }
        modifyResultToView(dividend, divisor);
        return result.toString();
    }

    private String makeDivider(Integer reminderNumber, Integer tab) {
        return assemblyString(tab, ' ') + assemblyString(calculateDigit(reminderNumber), '-');
    }

    private void modifyResultToView(Integer dividend, Integer divisor) {
        int[] index = new int[3];
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            if (result.charAt(i) == '\n') {
                index[j] = i;
                j++;
            }

            if (j == 3) {
                break;
            }
        }

        int tab = calculateDigit(dividend) + 1 - index[0];
        result.insert(index[2], assemblyString(tab, ' ') +"│" + quotient.toString());
        result.insert(index[1], assemblyString(tab, ' ') +"│" + assemblyString(quotient.length(), '-'));
        result.insert(index[0], "│" + divisor);
        result.replace(1, index[0], dividend.toString());
    }

    private int calculateDigit(int i) {
        return (int) Math.log10(i) + 1;
    }
    private String assemblyString(int numberOfSymbols, char symbol) {
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSymbols; i++) {
            string.append(symbol);
        }
        return string.toString();
    }
}
```

пример результата:

```
_10210│5
 10   │----
 --   │2042
  _21
   20
   --
   _10
    10
    --
     0
```

Пример теста:

```
Division division = new Division();

    @Test
    public void shouldMakeDivision() {
        String expected =   "_14789│20\n" + 
                            " 140  │---\n" + 
                            " ---  │739\n" + 
                            "  _78\n" + 
                            "   60\n" + 
                            "   --\n" + 
                            "  _189\n" + 
                            "   180\n" + 
                            "   ---\n" + 
                            "     9\n";
        assertEquals(expected, division.makeDivision(14789, 20));
    }
```